# Google places API using VBA in excel -- want to return an address of a nearby location based on keyword input and starting location

Tags: excel, google-places-api, vba

I'm a newbie to coding. I'm working on an excel spreadsheet where I have a few dozen locations defined as "latitude,longitude" and for each of those inputs I want to find the address of the nearest store based on a keyword (i.e., "Staples", "CVS", etc.).

I put together some code based on what I've been able to pick up from this forum and a few other places, but the result is showing as "-1" no matter what I input.

I think the problem might be with how I'm defining the output "regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)" this worked for me when I was writing a VBA to use Google's Distance API. Ideally what I want to have is the PlaceID or lat,long coordinates for the single closest location.

Here's the code I have (I omitted my API key from the code below, but have it in my version):

```
Public Function GetPlace(location As String, keyword As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, thirdVal As String, lastVal 
As String
    firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
    secondVal = "&location="
    thirdVal = "&keyword="
    lastVal = "&rankby=distance&sensor=false&key=[my API key]"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & secondVal & Replace(location, " ", "+") & thirdVal & 
    Replace(keyword, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """place"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", 
    Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetPlace = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetPlace = -1
End Function
```